# How to use pickle to save sklearn model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I want to dump and load my Sklearn trained model using Pickle. How to do that?

Comment: Check scikit-learn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) on model persistence.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Save:

```
import pickle

with open("model.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(model, f)
```

Load:

```
with open("model.pkl", "rb") as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

> In the specific case of scikit-learn, it may be better to use joblib’s
> replacement of pickle (dump & load), which is more efficient on
> objects that carry large numpy arrays internally as is often the case
> for fitted scikit-learn estimators:

Save:

```
import joblib

joblib.dump(model, "model.joblib")
```

Load:

```
model = joblib.load("model.joblib")
```

Comment: Hi @Mykola do you think that pickle is better than joblib in terms of saving the model ? because I have used joblib and unfortunately when I load the model for prediction, I always get the same predicted cluster. it seems like the model when saved is not trained!

Comment: already did : https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439968/k-means-gives-same-output-in-prediction

Answer (score 8):

Using pickle is same across all machine learning models irrespective of type i.e. clustering, regression etc.

To save your model in **dump** is used where 'wb' means write binary.

```
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb')) #Saving the model
```

To load the saved model wherever need **load** is used where 'rb' means read binary.

```
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb')) #To load saved model from local directory
```

Here model is kmeans and filename is any local file, so use accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

One can also use joblib

```
from joblib import dump, load
dump(model, model_save_path)
```