# While using Colab or Jupyter notebook is it possible to download the model and use it later on without starting from the top?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am training a model with a huge dataset and creating it every time is a huge hassel so I was wondering if there is a way to download the model and reuse it rather than creating and running it repeatedly everytime i use it. (i am a beginner)

i am expecting to download this model and use it multiple times rather than start from scratch then build and train it.

Comment: Typically, yes, but as you don't say which ML/DL framework (i.e. Tensorflow, Pytorch, etc.) you are using, it is difficult to say more than read the docs. Please edit the question to give us more detail, and a [minimal reproducible example].(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879434/how-to-use-pickle-to-save-sklearn-model) is an example for an sklearn-model, saved with either joblib or pickle.